# Styled Components / React - Style on Fragment element

Tags: reactjs, styles, styled-components

I have a question with StyledComponents, it's possible to create a style using a `React.Fragment` or any other existing component?

I use this example (The intention is the Style `ContainerFragment` paints the background on blue and use all the styles)

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mbv401920150/pen/OJLNVwj?&page=1)

If it's not possible, exists another workaround? Explicit using Fragment as an example.

---

**Update**: I made a specific question with my real problem on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57499833/styled-components-react-style-on-external-element)

Comment: You can create the fregment as you want and send props like color.
(https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you need to style a `Fragment` then you probably shouldn't be using it in the first place. `Fragments` exists as a workaround to return adjacent `JSX` elements, they don't render anything to the `DOM` so they can't be stylized.

This **isn't** correct:

```
const ContainerFragment = styled(React.Fragment)`
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: blue; 
`
```

A Fragment is not like a `div`. It won't render anything to the DOM, that's the entire point of having it.

Comment: It's possible I need to reformulate the question then.

Comment: I just create another question with my specific scenario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57499833/styled-components-react-style-on-external-element

Comment: Actually, it's useful to style a fragment cause this might be useful if you want to style their children instead of itself.

Comment: A fragment literally doesn't render anything to the DOM. There is no underlying element, there is no children by definition. That's the entire point of it

Answer (score 6):

`key` is the only attribute that can be passed to [`Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments).
In the future, we may add support for additional attributes, such as event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style a component directly, you will need to specify a HTML element.

In your case though (if you are only using it to style lower-level components) you could use something like React [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to pass down a prop that the [styled-component](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props) can consume and utilize to determine the style.

If you explicitly need the prop/value for styled-component usage, you could also use [styled-components transient props](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props).

Comment: This is a fine answer, but it's also worth asking at this point whether the css cascade might do some good here.  While it is less conventional in react component development, sometimes the use-case dictates a more traditional approach, and you can attach styles that apply to child elements en-masse (and targeted as specifically as needed) all within a single rule (Styled components supports nesting in both syntaxes).  This is at least a little more css-native than passing down abstractions. (to say nothing of theming which works quite well as you describe, via contexts)