# Styled Components / React - Style on external element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm using [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) components and [MaterialTable](https://material-table.com) and I want to stylish the components using [StyledComponents](https://www.styled-components.com/)

But I not been having the desired results when I try to apply styles using StyledComponents

[CodeSandBox Online Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/materialui-table-stylecomponent-yhtly)

Example:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import MaterialTable from "material-table";

export const MaterialTableStyled = styled(MaterialTable)`
    /* STYLE FOR FILTER ROW */
    tbody > .MuiTableRow-root:first-child {
        background-color: #F1F3F4 !important;
    }
`
```

When I use the `MaterialTableStyled` component no applied the style.

Instead, if I use a `div` on my StyledComponent:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const MaterialTableStyled = styled.div`
    /* STYLE FOR FILTER ROW */
    tbody > .MuiTableRow-root:first-child {
        background-color: #F1F3F4 !important;
    }
`
```

My custom styles work perfecty on that way:

```
<MaterialTableStyled> // DIV WITH STYLES
    <MaterialTable
        // ALL PROPS AND STUFFS
    />
</MaterialTableStyled>
```

...the question is: it's possible "override" or change styles without using the `div` to change the style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A component has to pass the className property into their children in order **styled** function to work.

From a quick look, MaterialTable doesn't do that, as a result styled components can't assign another css class to the table.

Component compatible with styled function

```
const StyledFriendlyComp = ({className}) => <div className={className}>Styles being applied</div>
```

Component that won't work with styled function

```
const StyledFriendlyComp = () => <div>Styles not working</div>
```

In this cases you need to wrap the component with another element like div.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style a component directly, you will need to specify a HTML element.

In your case though (if you are only using it to style lower-level components) you could use something like React [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to pass down a prop that the [styled-component](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props) can consume and utilize to determine the style.

If you explicitly need the prop/value for styled-component usage, you could also use set it as a styled-component [transient prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props).